# C++ Сложение огромных чисел

Tags: c++

Надо сложить 2 целых числа a и b, но при этом их сумма может доходить до 10^100. Я написал код, он работает только до определенного момента, когда пробуешь сложить например "111111111111111111111111111111" и "222222222222222222222222222222", ответ выдает уже не верный.

Как можно сложить два огромных числа в С++ чтобы их сумма могла доходить до 10^100 ?

Прилагаю код, но буду рад если вы покажете более простой способ решения.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int ia,ib;
int z=1;
string str1, str2;
cin>>str1>>str2;
int len1=str1.length();
int len2=str2.length();
char mas1[101], mas2[101];
int mas3[101];
double sk=0;
for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
{
strcpy(mas1, str1.c_str());
}
for(int i=0;i<len2;i++)
{
strcpy(mas2, str2.c_str());
}
int lenm=0;
    if(len1>len2){lenm=len1;}
    if(len2>len1){lenm=len2;}
    if(len1==len2){lenm=len1;}
for(int i=0;i<lenm;i++)
{
    if(len1<z){ib=0;}else{ia = mas1[len1-z] - '0';}
    if(len2<z){ib=0;}else{ib = mas2[len2-z] - '0';}
    sk+=((ia+ib)*(pow(10,z)))/10;
    z++;
}
cout<<setprecision(100)<<sk<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Спасибо за поправления, программа почти готова, но все равно есть одна ошибка. Когда складываем "11" и "11" выводит "22", а когда "15" и "15" вместо "30", выводит "20". В чем проблема?

Новый код прилагаю:

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    string str1, str2;
    cin>>str1>>str2;
    int len1=str1.length();
    int len2=str2.length();

    char mas1[101], mas2[101];
    int mas3[101], mas4[101];

    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
    {
    strcpy(mas1, str1.c_str());
    int ia = mas1[i] - '0';
    mas3[i] = ia;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<len2;i++)
    {
    strcpy(mas2, str2.c_str()); 
    int ia = mas2[i] - '0';
    mas4[i] = ia;
    }

    int length;
    if (len1 > len2)
        length = len1 + 1;
    else
        length = len2 + 1;

    for (int ix = 0; ix < length; ix++)
    {
        mas4[ix] += mas3[ix];
        mas4[ix + 1] += (mas4[ix] / 10);
        mas4[ix] %= 10; 
    }

    if (mas4[length - 1] == 0)
        length--;

    for(int i=0;i<len2;i++)
    {
    cout<<mas4[i];
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Не мучайтесь, и учтите, что собирать в double - ничего не даст, точности не хватит все равно. Если надо просто суммировать - то вообще работайте прямо со строками. Идете справа налево, суммируете по одной цифре с переносом в следующий разряд. Все не просто просто - а тривиально. Умножать (а тем паче делить) было бы куда большим геморроем. Попробуйте так; если не справитесь - тогда будем переходить к конкретному коду :)

Comment: Использование специализированных библиотек спасет вас: OpenSSL, GMP, Miracl (он ужасен) и так далее

Comment: Куда интересней  работать с такими числами с плавающей точкой ... Честно говоря я не понел  что вы хотели сделать, вызывая функцию strcpy в цикле ...

Comment: @Harry спасибо большое, я сделал все как вы описали, почти работает, но есть еще одна ошибка я описал ее выше.

Comment: Похоже, вы забыли о переносе - когда складываете 5 и 5, получается 10, т.е. пишем 0, но в следующем разряде нужно не забыть добавить лишнюю 1 - переност из предыдущего разряда.

Comment: @ не выходит, возможно я делаю не там перенос, но теперь другая ошибка стало записывать в разные разряды

Comment: @Harry все вышло, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код написан на С.

Вот корявый пример реализации (пожалуйста используйте этот код как отправную точку). Тем не менее этот код рабочий.

В качестве аргументов вы должны передать числа в функцию add_long_numbers в строковом представлении (со знаком минус или без в начале строки)

```
char* add_long_numbers_same_sign(const char* num1, const char* num2) {

    int len1 = strlen(num1);
    int len2 = strlen(num2);

    char sign1 = num1[0];
    char sign2 = num2[0];

    // Determine the sign of the result
    int sign = 1;
    if (num1[0] == '-') {
        sign *= -1;
        num1++;
        len1--;
    }
    if (num2[0] == '-') {
        sign *= -1;
        num2++;
        len2--;
    }

    // Allocate memory for the sum
    int maxSize = len1 > len2 ? len1 : len2;
    int* sum = (int*)calloc(maxSize + 1, sizeof(int));

    int carry = 0;
    int k = maxSize;
    int i = len1 - 1, j = len2 - 1;

    while (i >= 0 || j >= 0) {
        int digit1 = i >= 0 ? num1[i--] - '0' : 0;
        int digit2 = j >= 0 ? num2[j--] - '0' : 0;
        int total = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
        sum[k--] = total % 10;
        carry = total / 10;
    }

    if (carry > 0) {
        sum[k] += carry;
    }

    // Convert the sum to a string
    int start = (sum[k] == 0) ? k + 1 : k;
    int resultSize = maxSize - start + 2;
    char* result = (char*)malloc(resultSize * sizeof(char));
    
    for (int idx = start, r = 0; idx <= maxSize; idx++, r++) {
        result[r] = sum[idx] + '0';
    }
    result[resultSize - 1] = '\0';

    // Consider the sign of the result

    if (sign1 == '-' && sign2 == '-') {
        sign = -1;
    }

    if (sign == -1) {
        char* signedResult = (char*)malloc((resultSize + 1) * sizeof(char));
        signedResult[0] = '-';
        strcpy(signedResult + 1, result);
        free(result);
        free(sum);
        return signedResult;
    } else {
        free(sum);
        return result;
    }
}

char* add_long_numbers_different_sign(const char* num1, const char* num2) {

    char sign1 = num1[0];
    char sign2 = num2[0];

    const char* abs_num1 = (sign1 == '-' || sign1 == '+') ? num1 + 1 : num1;
    const char* abs_num2 = (sign2 == '-' || sign2 == '+') ? num2 + 1 : num2;

    int abs_len1 = strlen(abs_num1);
    int abs_len2 = strlen(abs_num2);

    int result_len = (abs_len1 > abs_len2 ? abs_len1 : abs_len2) + 1;

    char* result = (char*)malloc((result_len + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(5);
    }

    result[0] = '\0';

    int carry = 0;
    int i = abs_len1 - 1;
    int j = abs_len2 - 1;
    int k = result_len - 1;
    int abs_result_len = (abs_len1 > abs_len2 ? abs_len1 : abs_len2);

    while (i >= 0 || j >= 0 || carry > 0) {
        int digit1 = (i >= 0) ? abs_num1[i] - '0' : 0;
        int digit2 = (j >= 0) ? abs_num2[j] - '0' : 0;
        

        int difference = digit1 - digit2 - carry;

        // Если разница меньше 0, добавляем 10 и устанавливаем перенос
        if (difference < 0 && strlen(result) <= result_len) {
            difference += 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
        k--;
        sprintf(result + strlen(result), "%d", difference);

        if (i >= 0) i--;
        if (j >= 0) j--;
    }

    abs_result_len = strlen(result);


    removeTrailingZeros(result);

    reverseString(result); // Переворачиваем строку

    return result;
}

char* add_long_numbers(const char* num1, const char* num2) {

    char* result;
    
    if((num1[0] == '-' && num2[0] == '-') || (isdigit(num1[0]) && isdigit(num2[0]))) {
        result = add_long_numbers_same_sign( num1, num2);
    } else {

        char sign1 = num1[0];
        char sign2 = num2[0];


        const char* abs_num1 = (sign1 == '-' || sign1 == '+') ? num1 + 1 : num1;
        const char* abs_num2 = (sign2 == '-' || sign2 == '+') ? num2 + 1 : num2;

    
        int abs_len1 = strlen(abs_num1);
        int abs_len2 = strlen(abs_num2);


        if(compareStrings(abs_num1, abs_num2) == 1) {
            if(sign1 == '-') {
                result = add_long_numbers_different_sign( process_first_character(num1), process_first_character(num2));
                result = process_first_character(result);
            } else {
                result = add_long_numbers_different_sign( (num1), (num2));
            }
        } else {
            if(sign2 == '-') {
                result = add_long_numbers_different_sign( process_first_character(num2), process_first_character(num1));
                result = process_first_character(result);
            } else {
                result = add_long_numbers_different_sign( num2, num1);
            }
        }

    }
    

    return result;
}
```

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Не копипастите одинаковый код между несколькими ответами. Я бы удалил один из двух ответов.

Comment: Зачем писать 170 строк на другом языке, когда для решения достаточно десяти строк на C++?

Answer (score 0):

Есть масса информации на тему "Длинная арифметика" в С/С++ 
Например:

- http://cppstudio.com/post/5036/
- https://mindhalls.ru/big-number-in-c-cpp-add-sub/
- http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer

Comment: Спасибо, просмотрю, но не могли бы показать как это примерно будет работать, а то там только обрывки кода :(

Comment: @rengetsu, там целый класс `BigNumber`.